# Time taken by MapReduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs, distributed-computing

I am new to hadoop and mapreduce.I have a problem in running my data in hadoop Mapreduce. I want the results to be given in milliseconds. Is there any way that i can execute my Mapreduce jobs in milliseconds?
If not then what is the minimum time hadoop mapreduce can take in a fully distributed multi-cluster(5-6 nodes).
File size to be analyzed in hadoop mapreduce is around 50-100Mb
Program is written in Pig.Any suggesstions?

Comment: get a really really really fast computer.

Answer (score 1):

For adhoc realtime querying of data use [Imapala](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/IMPALA10BETADOC/Introducing+Cloudera+Impala), [Apache Drill](http://incubator.apache.org/drill/) (WIP). Drill is based on [Google Dremel](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36632.html).

Hive jobs get converted into MapReduce, so Hive is also batch oriented in nature and not real time. A lot of work is going on improve the performance of Hive ([1](http://hortonworks.com/blog/100x-faster-hive/) and [2](http://hortonworks.com/blog/45x-performance-increase-for-hive/)) though.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible(afaik). hadoop is not meant for real time stuff on the first place. it is best suitable for batch jobs. the mapreduce framework needs some time to accept and setup the job, which you can't avoid. and i don't think it's a wise decision to get ultra high end machines to setup a hadoop cluster. also, the framework has to do a few things before actually starting the job, creating the logical splits of your data, for instance.